# Hodge star operator and "Serre duality"

Tags: algebraic-geometry, duality-theorems, sheaf-cohomology, coherent-sheaves

I am familiar with the Hodge star operator or Hodge duality in the theory of finite-dimensional differentiable manifolds, which gives an isomorphism $\star:\Omega^{i}(M)\longrightarrow\Omega^{n-i}(M)$ if $M$ is an $n$-dimensional manifold. The existence of this star operator arises essentially from the perfect product $\Omega^{i}(M)\wedge\Omega^{n-i}(M)\longrightarrow\Omega^{n}(M)$.

Deligne and Illusie (https://eudml.org/doc/143480, p. 255) make the claim that this can be generalized to the case where $X\longrightarrow S$ is a proper smooth morphism of $\mathbb{F}_{p}$ schemes with $\dim(X/S)=n$ and claim that in this case $\Omega^{i}_{X/S}$ and $\Omega^{n-i}_{X/S}$ are dual over $\Omega^{n}_{X/S}$. This is apparently called Serre duality, but I have difficulties to find an exact proof of this claim. (I am probably too stupid to do a decent literature research). Does anybody have a link or a book reference?

Comment: If you're only looking for $\Omega^i\otimes\Omega^{n-i}\to\Omega^n$ being a perfect pairing, this is just the statement that $\Omega_{X/S}$ is locally free for any smooth morphism $X\to S$ and the fact that on any ringed space with locally free sheaf $F$ of rank $n$ and any $0\leq r\leq n$, the multiplication map $\bigwedge^r F \otimes\bigwedge^{n-r} F \to \bigwedge^n F$ is a perfect pairing. Both of these statements are in most books in some capacity - for instance, the case of $S$ the spectrum of a field is Hartshorne thm II.8.17, and the pairing is exercise II.5.16.